# Image-sorting script in python not working as intended

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a script in Python that sorts images by dates into folders by the day it was taken, and I finished it, but it doesn't work as intended. When I run the code, it makes a folder titled as the current date with no contents inside the folder, since nothing was taken that day. This is the code:

```
#modules
import os, time, datetime, platform, glob, shutil

#file variables
path = 'E:/Images/Dest/'
filenames = glob.glob(path+'*')
dictionary = {}


#functions
def file_creation(file):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file))

for file in filenames:
    file_time = file_creation(file)

#formatting variables
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file))
file_date = timestamp.strftime("%Y %m %d")


dictionary[file] = file_date
print(dictionary)

#file backup
log = ''


#directory creation
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if not os.path.exists(path+value):
        os.makedirs(path+value)
    filename = key.split('/')
    filename = filename[-1]
    if not os.path.exists(path+value+'/'+filename):
        print(path+value+'/'+filename)
        if os.path.isfile(key):
            shutil.move(key,path+value+'/'+filename)
            log = log + key + ' moved to ' + path+value+'/'+filename+'\n+'+'\n'
        elif os.path.isdir(key):
            shutil.copytree(key, path+value+'/'+filename)
            shutil.rmtree(key)
            log = log + key + ' moved to ' + path+value+'/'+filename+'\n'+'\n'

#log
with open(path+'log.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(log)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What include in  the log.txt?

Comment: I wrote the log to record what happens, but it doesn't appear either.

Comment: It looks like you may have the wrong indentation in your first loop because you aren’t using your file_time variable. Is that your actual indentation or an error when formatting for stackoverflow?